# Exercise on Venn diagrams.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

At an international conference on environmental pollution, they attend

90 specialists, of which 33 speak English, 52 Portuguese and 45 Spanish;

28 of them speak Portuguese and English; 22 English and Spanish; 15 Portuguese and

Spanish. How many attendees speak the three languages?

Who help me, with this. Please.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What attempts have you done so far?

Comment: Making the diagrams, and calculating the respective cardinals, the answer gave me 25. Okay?

Comment: I also got 25 using a formula for number of elements in the union of three sets.

Comment: I wouldn't know Venn diagrams but you can basically say $52+33+45-90 = 40$ are found too many assuming people only speak one language. Then assume all those people who speak more then one only speak one, we still find $22+15+28-40 = 25$ too many, so 25 people speak 3 languages. Then again, this looks like a homework question in which case you are better of learning for yourself how to do this with actual venn diagrams than copy some stranger on the internet ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  It is a good practice to at least sketch your attempt at solving the problem when you post it.  This gives Readers a better start on responding in a way you will find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

$|E \cup P \cup S| =90$, as there $90$ people in total.

We know that $$|E \cup P \cup S| = |E| + |P| + |S| - |E \cap P| - |E \cap S| -|P \cap S| + |E \cap P \cap S|$$

by the inclusion-exclusion formula. E.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Plugging in your data:

$$90 = 33 + 52 + 45 - 28 -22 -15  + |E \cap P \cap S|$$

so  $$90 = 65  + |E \cap P \cap S|$$

so $25 = 90 - 65$ speak all three. Venn diagrams are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 way intersection of 25 noted above in various responses is greater than 2 of the 2 way intersections of 22 and 15. That's a problem.

Comment: You are correct and the solvers are also correct.  The problem is infeasible; no such school can exist.